# React icons not loading with webpack

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use react-icons in my project https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons

My webpack file looks like this :

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
  __DEV__: true
};

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`, // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/', // Use absolute paths to avoid the way that URLs are resolved by Chrome when they're parsed from a dynamically loaded CSS blob. Note: Only necessary in Dev.
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS), // Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.htmlnew webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']}
    ]
  }
};
```

It has an svg loader so there shouldn't be an issue, however, I get the following error 
`ERROR in ./~/react-icons/ti/thumbs-down.js
Module parse failed: /Users/Projects/react-slingshot/node_modules/react-icons/ti/thumbs-down.js Unexpected token (8:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:12)`

Not sure what I'm missing in order to load these in my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-icons/ti/thumbs-down.js` contains untranspiled ES6+JSX source.

You need to import from `react-icons/lib/ti/thumbs-down.js` to get the ES5 version, since you're only using Babel on your own `src/` directory.

This is mentioned in the [README's Usage section](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons#usage).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that