# react-icons resolve error with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I saw the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270582/react-icons-not-loading-with-webpack) about [react-icons](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons) not loading in webpack but the error I'm getting is a bit different and I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm trying to use react-icons with webpack but I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in ./components/line-item.jsx
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-icons' in public/map/components @ ./components/line-item.jsx 7:18-40

Here is my webpack setup:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
    iconPath: 'node_modules/react-icons'
};

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js'},
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
          },
          {
            test: /react-icons\/(.)*(.js)$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            include: config.iconPath
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss/,
            loader: 'style!css!sass'
          }
      ]
   }
};
```

Here is where I'm trying to import the react-icons in my line-item.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import FaBeer from 'react-icons';

var LineItem = React.createClass({
})

module.exports = LineItem;
```

I'm brand new to webpack and just learning as I'm going but any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
I changed the import to

```
import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer';
```

and now getting a different error that I do believe is webpack related

> ERROR in ./~/react-icons/fa/beer.js
>   Module parse failed: /Users/oyachinskiy/Documents/ichnaea-root/web-reporting/public/map/node_modules/react-icons/fa/beer.js Unexpected token (8:12)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your import from:

```
import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer';
```

To:

```
import FaBeer from 'react-icons/lib/fa/beer';
```

That resolved the "Module parse failed" problem you're describing for me.

Answer (score 2):

By default babel ignores the node_modules directory. Unless you change that setting, you need to import the icons from the lib directory.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons/issues/4) for more details.

To import one icon:

```
import FaBeer from 'react-icons/lib/fa/beer'
```

To import multiple icons:

```
import { MdCancel, MdChat, MdCheck } from 'react-icons/lib/md'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have run `npm install react-icons`then you should just be able to require it in your component. I don't believe you need to adjust the webpack configuration.

EDIT--

The correct syntax is:

`import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer';`

As per their [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons).

Comment: I have react-icons installed as a a dependency but that does not work either.  Same error occurs when I simply try to require it.

Comment: See my edited answer - your syntax does not match their docs.

Comment: Ok upon doing that I get a different error...  ERROR in ./~/react-icons/fa/beer.js
Module parse failed web-reporting/public/map/node_modules/react-icons/fa/beer.js Unexpected token (8:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.  This is why I think I need to edit the webpack config

Answer (score 0):

The right way to import is `import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer'` http://gorangajic.github.io/react-icons/index.html[enter link description here](http://gorangajic.github.io/react-icons/index.html).

In the new versions of webpack it is necessary to put the suffix `-loader`

```
{
  test: /react-icons\/(.)*(.js)$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and it took me decades to solve it.

You should import it this way

import {FaBeer} from 'react-icons/lib/fa/beer'